# pdftk on Lubuntu 18.04 - is it possible?

Tags: command-line, package-management, lubuntu, pdftk

Today I've migrated onto Lubuntu 18.04 from Ubuntu 16.04. Got a lot of scripts that use pdftk tool. But now I can't install it either with `apt-get` or with synaptic. Tried to install from deb - got a lot of unresolved dependencies, `--fix-broken` just deletes it.

Is there any effective way to get this tool installed?

Comment: Where did you get the deb from? AFAICT, Bionic does not carry `pdftk` at this time: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdftk. Have you tried compiling from source? There's something here: https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/

Comment: Got deb for artful, thought it have a chance to be compatible. Looks like "no".

Comment: When trying to make from source it says that I'm need to install gcj-jdk, but it seems like there is no version for 18.04. Is it any hope that it will be available later?

Comment: Please mark [pdftk missing in bionic](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pdftk/+bug/1764450) as "affects me too". Note that you need to sign into Launchpad to do so.

Comment: Also have a look here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028522/how-can-i-install-pdftk-in-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-shell-version-no-gtk/1028983#comment1675471_1028983 for a workaround